# codesigning issues with multiple binaries on the same path

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

Ive been trying to create a build of my program signed with my mac developer ID but i keep getting the error message "Multiple binaries share the same codesign path". I have checked the code signatures on each of the attached frameworks using the codesign terminal ultity and there doesnt seem to be any codesigning issues.If it helps the frameworks which seem to causing the problem are SDL2, SDL2_image, SDL2_mixer and SDL2_ttf. Also i am running Xcode 6.1.1 on yosemite 10.10.2

[image: Xcode error message]

[image: Frameworks being copied into app bundle]

Comment: this question needs more info: how are you doing your code signing?  did you set a build setting? or are you doing this via exporting from archived apps?  or are you doing it solely from the command line?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am doing my code signing as part of my build process via xcode. I have a build process which copies the frameworks into the application bundle and signs them. The build settings being used are default.

Comment: i would add a image of the error but i dont have enough rep points to do so

Comment: added image of error

Comment: Does your build process copy frameworks by following symlinks?  To be specific, I think what's happening here is that `"webp`" at "`/Applications/PickUpStix.app/Contents/Frameworks/webp.framework/Versions/Current/`" is a symbolic link.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann ok i checked and yes frameworks are copied by following symlinks, what do i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: show me how frameworks are copied (i.e. another screenshot?)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann added a second screenshot showing how the frameworks are being copied

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same error.

Comment: Me too. I used find to look in the frameworks and it finds no symlinks.

Comment: Did anyone of you find the solution? I'm having the same problem and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Archive folder and delete all previous built version before your code signing was made. Try again after.